# Webpack: errors during npm run prod

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react project which was already created by create-react-app. I want to use webpack in it, so started installing babel, loaders etc.

My package.json scripts file looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "clean": "npx rimraf ./build",
    "build:prod": "react-scripts build",
    "commit": "git-cz --no-verify",
    "precommit": "yarn lint && yarn pretty",
    "pretty": "pretty-quick --pattern \"**/*.*(ts|tsx|html|scss|css)\" --staged",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" --fix",
    "commitmsg": "commitlint -e $GIT_PARAMS",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --mode=development",
    "prod": "npm run webpack -- --mode=production"
}
```

And my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
    const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = ({ mode } = { mode: "production" }) => {
    console.log(`mode is: ${mode}`);

    return {
            mode,
            entry: "./src/index.js",
            output: {
                publicPath: "/",
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
                filename: "bundled.js"
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                 {
                    test: /\.jpe?g|png$/,
                    enforce: "pre",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: [" ", "url-loader", "file-loader"]
                },
                    {
                        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                        enforce: "pre",
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            plugins: [
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    template: "./public/index.html"
                }),
            ]
        }
};
```

Errors:

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - configuration.module.rules[0] should be one of these:    ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?,
>   generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?,
>   parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?,
>   resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]    ->
>   A rule.    Details:
>
>   - configuration.module.rules[0].loader should be a non-empty string.
>     -> A loader request.

Although my build folder was already present, I have no idea from where exactly it was created.
My goal is to minify my javascript so I am going with webpack here. How do I proceed?

Comment: Replace `loader: [" ", "url-loader", "file-loader"]` with  `loader: ["url-loader", "file-loader"]`

Comment: Yes, that resolved that issue, but now it says "configuration.module.rules[0]" error on this. Although I have added the similar " " in second rule too.